# Bundle Product Related Issue in Magento 2.1.12

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

Bundle product is having any limit of add simple product?I was already add 55 products but i want more.Can it is possible?Please Help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No. I dont think there is any limit but you should make sure your PHP configuration is able to save the product correctly. You need to make sure 
`post_max_size` , `max_execution_time` and `max_input_vars` settings are setup properly.